# How to solve Error: Unable to initialize main class selection.ClustererExecution

Tags: java, weka

I want to do some work with weka in java. I've added the weka-src.jar and the weka-dev-3.7.10 jar in the java build path and my code doesn't show any error before running it. After I run the code it gives me the following error

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class selection.ClustererExecution
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/filters/Filter
```

Here is my code:

```
    package selection;
    import weka.clusterers.ClusterEvaluation;
    import weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans;

import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import weka.filters.*;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove;

public class ClustererExecution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //Loading data
            Instances data = DataSource.read("/Data_Cortex_Nuclear.arff");
            System.out.println("The number of attributes is: " + data.numAttributes() + " while the number of instances is: " + data.numInstances());
            data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);
            System.out.println("The class index is: " + data.classIndex()); 
            //Create copy without class attribute
            Remove rem = new Remove();
            rem.setAttributeIndices("" + (data.classIndex() + 1));
            rem.setInputFormat(data);
            Instances dataClusterer = Filter.useFilter(data, rem);
            //Build clusterer
            SimpleKMeans clusterer = new SimpleKMeans();
            clusterer.setMaxIterations(100);
            clusterer.setNumClusters(8);
            clusterer.buildClusterer(dataClusterer);
            //Evaluate clusterer with original data
            ClusterEvaluation eval = new ClusterEvaluation();
            eval.setClusterer(clusterer);
            eval.evaluateClusterer(data);
            System.out.println(eval.clusterResultsToString());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix the error?I am using eclipse if that makes any difference. Thank you!

Comment: seems like the file isnt in the right folder. Is it in a folder called `selection` to match the package name?

Comment: You may have added the weka jars to the _build_ path, but the relevant weka jar needs to be in the classpath when running too.

Comment: @JohnD the ClustererExecution class is inside the selection package

Comment: @Zastai you were right. I had them in the Modulepath. Now it works. Thank you!

Comment: ok i will resolve this then! Glad you got your issue fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments below by Zastai, you added the weka jars to the build path, but the relevant weka jar needs to be in the classpath as well.